# Using CURL to get remote page source code and create new HTML file with variable name

Tags: php, curl

After doing 3 hours of research and reading i decided to post this question to share what i reached and asking for your help,

here is what I am trying to do I have created .php file executing 3 operations:

1-curl function to get the source code of remote page.

2-creating a new html file containing the code got from the remote page.

3-open this file in current window

i tried to make it basic at first applying it on google.com as remote page and local host.

the file test.php which present in localhost/test.php and the code is:

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://google.com";

    //Get the html of url
    function get_data($url) 
    { 
       $ch = curl_init();
       $timeout = 5;
       //$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.";
       $userAgent = "IE 7 – Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;

    }

    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $fp = @fopen('google.html', 'w') or die('Could not open file, or fike does not exist and failed to create.');
    $mytext = $html;
    @fwrite($fp, $mytext) or die('Could not write to file.');
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = 'google.html'; //Will take you to Google.
    </script>
```

and it works perfect :D so i have proceeded  to apply on actual site where the remote page link is got dynamically from the code below:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getQueryVariable(variable,def) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }
  return def;
}
function redirect(){
    window.location.href = 'static/popups/'+getQueryVariable('event_id',0)+getQueryVariable('tv_id',0)+getQueryVariable('tid',0)+getQueryVariable('channel',0)+'.html';
} 
</script>
<body onload="redirect()">
<style>body{background-color: #000000; text-align: center;}</style>
</body></html>
```

so the resulting link will be something like this http://remotepage.com/static/popups/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.html where xxxxxxxxxxxxx will be numbers got from the code above

how can i get the code of xxxxxxxxxxxxx.html and create html file named xxxxxxxxxxxxx.html at mysite.com/static/popups/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getQueryVariable(variable,def) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);  //Returns the query string of the URL.   Eg, anything after "?" in the url.
  var vars = query.split("&");                      //This and the next couple lines just find the right key in the url
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }
  return def;
}
function redirect(){
    window.location.href = 'static/popups/'+getQueryVariable('event_id',0)+getQueryVariable('tv_id',0)+getQueryVariable('tid',0)+getQueryVariable('channel',0)+'.html';
} 
</script>
```

So, the quick and easy way to get it is to grab the query string of the url using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).
Then, you parse that using [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).
After that, just fill in the bits and pieces into the url that you were suppose to go to.

Parse_str returns a named array.  So, if your query string is `?event_id=2&tv_id=100`, you can get the event_id by going to `$arr['event_id']` after you parse the string.
Then, replace each call to the function with the matching variable.
`getQueryVariable('event_id',0)` would be replaced with $arr['event_id'].

If the parameter is not defined, you get 0 instead.

Comment: can You just simplify it i new to php and programming

Comment: Updated a little bit.  It's enough for you to piece it together.

Comment: "just fill in the bits and pieces into the url that you were suppose to go to" after i get the link what i have to do you didn't answered my question